# How to use CFilter Yii

Tags: php, yii

If I want to create a simple mechanism such as the `rights` extension that serves limiting and checking the access rights to the `action` is that I have to do on each of my controller ie `preFilter` ?

For example in the case. I create a table with a set of user authentication in the table below :

`1 = Allow` and `0 = Not Allow`

[image: My Table]

Every controller I have, if the user `requests` to the action it will always be `checked` whether the current user has `permissions` or not

I see here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller that this can be done

```
class PerformanceFilter extends CFilter
{
    protected function preFilter($filterChain)
    {
        // logic being applied before the action is executed
        return true; // false if the action should not be executed
    }

    protected function postFilter($filterChain)
    {
        // logic being applied after the action is executed
    }
}
```

How do I order to be able to use it with the `AR` in Yii to be able to do this?

Or is there a better way for this case?

Does it help to not make the same code over and over again in every `action` to check the authorization of users that access is `permitted or not`

Thanks